# oracle SQL left join base on table value and other criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I have two tables:

Table_A

| Type | Sub_type | ID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3314 | A23451 | 740 |
| A | 3370 | A12341 | 12340 |
| B | 7351 | B43671 | 4325 |
| A | 3324 | A56712 | 1245 |
| A | 3311 | A23457 | 98345 |
| A | 3311 | A13451 | 60 |
| A | 3314 | A23451 | 78901 |

Table_B

| Subtype | Value_1 | Value_2 | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3314 | 0 | 999.99 | 0 |
| 3314 | 1000 | unlimited | 2.5 |
| 3370 | 0 | 200 | 0 |
| 3370 | 0 | unlimited | 5 |
| 3324 | 0 | 999.99 | 0 |
| 3324 | 1000 | 49999.99 | 2 |
| 3324 | 50000 | unlimited | 4 |
| 3311 | 0 | 999.99 | 0 |
| 3311 | 1000 | unlimited | 2.5 |
| 3314 | 0 | 2499.99 | 0 |
| 3314 | 2500 | unlimited | 7 |

I need to map based on the correct sub_type and amount level looked into the table_B value_1 and value_2 and pick the correct rate applicable (only for type A)

output as follows:

| Type | Sub_type | ID | Amount | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3314 | A23451 | 740 | 2.5 |
| A | 3370 | A12341 | 12340 | 2.5 |
| B | 7351 | B43671 | 4325 | NULL |
| A | 3324 | A56712 | 1245 | 5 |
| A | 3311 | A23457 | 98345 | 2.5 |
| A | 3311 | A13451 | 60 | 0 |
| A | 3314 | A23451 | 78901 | 7 |

SQL I designed:

```
select A.*, (CASE A.Type = 'A' and a.amount >= b.value_1 and a.amount =< value_2 THEN B.RATE) AS RATE
from table_A  A
Left join table_B  B 
ON A.Sub_type  = B.Sub_type
```

but my output getting duplicate & incorrect rate captured.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Move `case` conditions to the `join` conditions

Comment: I tried the same but still duplicates

Answer (score -1):

There are some serious inconsistencies in your TABLE_B data. Some of values 1 and 2 are overlaping the possible amounts. secondly, your Select couldn't possibly output anything except an error message.
Not completely understanding what you want to get out of it, I can just make a guess how it could make any sense.
So, the guess is:

```sql
WITH
    tab_a AS
        (
          SELECT 'A' "TYPE_", '3314' "SUB_TYPE", 'A23451' "ID", 740 "AMOUNT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 'A' "TYPE_", '3370' "SUB_TYPE", 'A12341' "ID", 12340 "AMOUNT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 'B' "TYPE_", '7351' "SUB_TYPE", 'B43671' "ID", 4325 "AMOUNT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 'A' "TYPE_", '3324' "SUB_TYPE", 'A56712' "ID", 1245 "AMOUNT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 'A' "TYPE_", '3311' "SUB_TYPE", 'A23457' "ID", 98345 "AMOUNT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 'A' "TYPE_", '3311' "SUB_TYPE", 'A13451' "ID", 60 "AMOUNT" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 'A' "TYPE_", '3314' "SUB_TYPE", 'A23451' "ID", 78901 "AMOUNT" FROM DUAL 
        ),
    tab_b AS
        (
          SELECT '3314' "SUB_TYPE",     '0' "VALUE_1",      '999.99' "VALUE_2",     '0' "RATE"      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT '3314' "SUB_TYPE",     '1000' "VALUE_1",   'unlimited' "VALUE_2",  '2.5' "RATE"    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT '3370' "SUB_TYPE",     '0' "VALUE_1",      '200' "VALUE_2",        '0' "RATE"      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT '3370' "SUB_TYPE",     '0' "VALUE_1",      'unlimited' "VALUE_2",  '5' "RATE"      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT '3324' "SUB_TYPE",     '0' "VALUE_1",      '999.99' "VALUE_2",     '0' "RATE"      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT '3324' "SUB_TYPE",     '1000' "VALUE_1",   '49999.99' "VALUE_2",   '2' "RATE"      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT '3324' "SUB_TYPE",     '50000' "VALUE_1",  'unlimited' "VALUE_2",  '4' "RATE"      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT '3311' "SUB_TYPE",     '0' "VALUE_1",      '999.99' "VALUE_2",     '0' "RATE"      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT '3311' "SUB_TYPE",     '1000' "VALUE_1",   'unlimited' "VALUE_2",  '2.5' "RATE"    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT '3314' "SUB_TYPE",     '0' "VALUE_1",      '2499.99' "VALUE_2",    '0' "RATE"      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT '3314' "SUB_TYPE",     '2500' "VALUE_1",   'unlimited' "VALUE_2",  '7' "RATE"      FROM DUAL 
        ),
    group_b AS
        (
            SELECT
                SUB_TYPE "SUB_TYPE", RATE "RATE", Min(To_Number(VALUE_1)) "VALUE_1", Max(To_Number(REPLACE(VALUE_2, 'unlimited', '999999'))) "VALUE_2"
            FROM
                tab_b
            GROUP BY SUB_TYPE, RATE
            ORDER BY SUB_TYPE, To_Number(VALUE_1), To_Number(REPLACE(VALUE_1, 'unlimited', '999999'))
        )
SELECT
    a.TYPE_ "TYPE", a.SUB_TYPE "SUB_TYPE", a.ID "ID",
    b.VALUE_1, REPLACE(To_Char(b.VALUE_2), '999999', 'unlimited'),
    a.AMOUNT "AMOUNT",
    CASE WHEN A.TYPE_ = 'A' And a.AMOUNT Between To_Number(b.VALUE_1) And To_Number(REPLACE(b.VALUE_2, 'unlimited', '999999')) THEN b.RATE END "RATE"
FROM
    tab_a a
INNER JOIN
    group_b b ON(b.SUB_TYPE = a.SUB_TYPE)
WHERE
    a.TYPE_ = 'A' And 
    CASE WHEN A.TYPE_ = 'A' And a.AMOUNT Between To_Number(b.VALUE_1) And To_Number(REPLACE(b.VALUE_2, 'unlimited', '999999')) THEN b.RATE END Is Not Null
ORDER BY a.SUB_TYPE, b.VALUE_1
--  
--      R e s u l t
--  
--  TYPE    SUB_TYPE  ID            VALUE_1      VALUE_2     AMOUNT    RATE
--  ------- --------  ------       --------   ---------- ----------    ------- 
--  A       3311      A13451              0   999.99            60     0    
--  A       3311      A23457           1000   unlimited      98345     2.5  
--  A       3314      A23451              0   2499.99          740     0    
--  A       3314      A23451           1000   unlimited      78901     2.5  
--  A       3314      A23451           2500   unlimited      78901     7    
--  A       3324      A56712           1000   49999.99        1245     2    
--  A       3370      A12341              0   unlimited      12340     5
```

The with clause creating data for tab_a and tab_b are for testing purposes only, it is not part of the query.
To test the query on your actual data, remove that part of the with clause, and use your actual table and column names.
CTE named group_b is here as an attempt to consolidate the tab_b data. If it is not needed you can remove it and in the main select put tab_b instead of group_b in wich case the complete with clause can be deleted. Regards...